# How do I obtain a non-empty optional with the value inside it being default constructed?

Tags: c++, c++17, option-type, default-constructor

Let's say I have a default constructed, thus empty, object `ov` of type `std::optional<std::vector<int>>`.

Yeah, `std::vector` can express the concept of being empty without the help of `std::optional`, but bear with me.

And then let's say that, based on some logic, I decide that I have to fill it with a vector on which I want to `push_back` elements one by one. How do I do?

It looks to me that the following is a bit ugly:

```cpp
ov = decltype(ov)::value_type{};
ov.push_back(/* something */);
ov.push_back(/* something else */);
```

Is this really the way to go about it?

Comment: If one goes over to the cppreference page of `std::optional`, they'll find this dandy method https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/emplace

Comment: Also the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) that takes the `std::in_place_t` can be used to distinguish between "default construct the `optional`" and "construct an `optional` whose starting value was default-constructed"

Comment: @NathanPierson To be extremely pedantic, the `in_place_t` constructor can be used to value-initialize the object, not default-initialize it. But luckily, the OP is talking about a vector, in which case they're the same thing.

Comment: Good catch @BrianBi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is

```
std::optional<std::vector<int>> ov = {{}};
```

alternatives include

```
std::optional<std::vector<int>> ov(std::in_place);
```

sadly there is no way to do this with assignment instead of construction; `{{}}` is ambiguous, and the `std::in_place` constructor is explicit.

There you have to call `ov.emplace()`.

You could create a helper object;

```
struct non_empty {
  template<class T>
  constexpr operator std::optional<T>()const{ return {{}}; }
};
```

then

```
ov = non_empty{};
```

does the job.

Answer (score 6):

For any default-constructible type `T`, you can create an `optional<T>` with a default-constructed `T` via `std::optional<T>(std::in_place)`. This will perform in-place construction with no parameters.

If you already have such an `optional<T>` instance, you can simply call `obj.emplace()` on it.